# Azure DB restore

Tags: azure, database

The data got wiped of accidentally. The database we are using is of pricing tier Standard Geo-Replication the earliest restoration time is the time when the db got dropped and created.is there a way can we get the DB restored

Answer (score 1):

Yes, standard databases are backed up regularly so you can restore them using the Azure portal. You need to go to the database server that held the database and use the backup/restore option there to select the restore point. See here for details - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups#deleted-database-restore

If you deleted the server as well as the database then you cannot restore through the portal, you need to raise a support request to get that restored.